# Signing and Verifing config files on mobile devices (iOS + Android)

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We have an app that stores some data localy, none of this data is valuable to anyone else except the user and us. So, we don't need to encrypt it, but we do want to make sure that nobody has changed it.

I figured the easiest way to do this is to generate a hash from file contents, date stamp and/or size. Doing straight md5 is probably not good enough, because who ever wants to change the data could just generate a new hash, so it would be nice to use some sort of the key. Does anybody know of a simple way to do this? I would like to avoid using libraries such as crypto++, but not 100% against it.

Oh, and we are doing the app in C++.

Maybe, I just need to add some obscure data to whatever we pass to the md5 function and be done with this. What do you guys think?

Just to reiterate, file has no valuable info to hackers, so there is no reason to go overboard with security. I just want to check if the settings have been messed with.

Thanks,
Angrius.

PS> does anyone know a good way to implement md5 that would work on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do what i wanted to do is to implement basic HMAC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). You can even store this hash inside the config file itself, although that's a bit more complicated, but pretty neat.

Turns out that both iOS and Android have built in libraries to do basic SHA1, MD5 and so on. They also both support HMAC. So for iOS you would do something like this:

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

string createHMAC( string key, string text )
{
    string result;

    const char *cKey  = key.c_str();
    const char *cData = text.c_str();
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac( kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC );

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", cHMAC[i]];
    }
    result = string( [output UTF8String] );

    return result;
}
```

Since this is objective-c code, you can compile this as objective-c++ and it will work. If your app doesn't require any advanced cryptography, there is no need to use any frameworks.

Cheers,
Angrius

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sign the data, you will need to use a key and a signature algorithm. Either an asymmetric one like RSA or a symmetric one such as AES. However, if your app needs to sign data with it, the key needs to be embedded or otherwise made available to the app. In that case a potential attacker can extract it from the app and create their own, valid signatures. You decide if that is OK with you and how far you want to go in protecting it.

Adding 'obscure data' or otherwise trying to come up with your own algorithm is a bad idea, you are bound to get it wrong, especially if you don't have experience in this field. Do use a standard algorithm, and think how you will protect keys (use iOS key chain, etc.). Search for "RSA sigantures" or "HMAC" to get more details about how to do this in practice. If you cannot take advantage of the platform's cryptographic APIs from your C++ library(?), you will need to use and link to a third-party library such as OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not trying to protect the data, I am just trying to see if anyone has modified it. I would reject the config file if it was modified and revert to defaults. It seems it would be an overkill to use OpenSSL for this.

Comment: There is no way to be sure it was not modified if don't hold some sort of signing key (even you say so in the OP :).

Comment: Yeah, I think i am going to generated md5 based on the file's meta data and some private key, kinda like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Comment: 'Kinda' is always *bad*. Use a standard algorithm with a sufficiently strong key, preferably via a well-known library. Otherwise you might just drop the whole checking thing.